# Data is not always loaded on the realtime

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

When I call my application, I want to read a list of all the content in my Firebase Realtime DB.
For this I use the useEffect function in React.
But now it is the case that the data is not loaded every time, which means: If I'm lucky, data comes up, if not, I have to press the refresh button of the browser several times.
Why is that so ?

```
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue } from "firebase/database";

React.useEffect(() => {
let array = [];

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getDatabase(firebaseApp);
const starCountRef = ref(db, "articel");

onValue(
  starCountRef,
  (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      array.push(child.val());
    });
  },
  {
    onlyOnce: true,
  }
);
setArtikel(array);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting state right away, before any values come back. You need to wait until you get a snapshot, and *then* create the array and set state.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = getDatabase(firebaseApp);
  const starCountRef = ref(db, "articel");

  onValue(
    starCountRef,
    (snapshot) => {
      let array = [];
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        array.push(child.val());
      });
      setArtikel(array);
    },
    {
      onlyOnce: true,
    }
  );
}, []);
```